# Separating a list and saving as individual values from a text file

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop, while-loop

What are some simple ways of separating a list from a text file? I want to save each value of the list and assign it to a variable.

Comment: for starter don't name a variable `list` you are overriding `list` which is important

Comment: Please provide examples of the file you are reading, and what kind of date a user might provide.

Comment: now that has made an error and the program won't work when I changed the name list to another variable

Comment: Again you are not being very specific. What error are you getting? Please show your updated program, input, expected results and output.

Comment: Okay I worked out that the error was coming from the empty for loop. So my main question is really just what needs to go into the for loop so that I can assign a variable to each number (the line that follows the date that was inputted).